# HTML link on input button

Tags: html, input, hyperlink

I want to know how do i put link on input button in html pages. As of now i am trying to make a link on input button by putting hyperlinks around buttons but can it be possible with any other method to navigate to another page?

**curretly i am doing like this:**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Practise 20</title>
      <style>
         input[type="submit"]{border:none; background:#000; color:#fff}
      </style>
   <body>
      Click on Button to navigate the Pages
         <form>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="self"><input type="submit" Value="Go"></a>
         </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can put link on input buttons by java script.. try like this

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Practise 20</title>
   <style>
      input[type="submit"]{border:none; background:#000; color:#fff}
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      Click on Button to navigate the Pages
      <form>
         <input onClick="window.location.href='put your page url here'" type="submit" Value="Go">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the capitalization necessary/required? I usually see `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

You might get it to work better with a simple javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function google() {
window.location = "http://google.com";
}
</script>
```

And as of the HTML part:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" onClick="google()">
```

Comment: Or simpler `<input type="submit" value="Go" onClick="window.location = 'http://google.com';">`

Answer (score 1):

Attribute ***formaction*** works pretty well. Here is an example:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="login.html" value="Submit to another page">
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how do i put link on input button in html pages?

You don't. Links are links. Buttons are buttons. One cannot be placed inside the other in HTML.

If you want a link that looks like a button, then use a link and apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

Comment: i want input button that onclick jumps to another page. As above both the answer worked fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://www.google.com"><input type="submit" Value="Go"></form>
```

Please note that you should not use submit buttons for hyperlinking purpose. Submit button is for submitting a form, therefore linking it to a page send the wrong info to the user. Still you can do it; if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this. You can have a form with a post action to the route, then use bootstrap classes to disguise the input as a nav link

```
<form action="/Rooms/Edit/:id" method="POST" style="margin: 0 1rem;">
      <input  class="btn btn-link" value="Edit Rooms" type="submit" style="font-weight: bold; text-dectoration:none">  
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="self"><input type="submit" Value="Go"></a>
```

Very simple! Just put some bootstrap classes into it and add role as button. That's it!

```
<a class="btn btn-success" role="button" href="http://www.google.com" target="self"><input type="submit" Value="Go"></a>
```

Comment: This assumes that the Bootstrap toolkit is used, but there is no indication in the question that this is the case.